# python re.sub behavior changed with 3.7. Bug or not?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

A python script of mine started misbehaving in recent versions.  I tracked it down to a  `re` substitution that behaves differently in python <=3.6 vs >= 3.7  Newer python versions make the substitution **twice**.

Did something break in python `re` or am I doing something wrong and finally got caught?

As I understand it, the regex `r'[^_]*$'` in the example code below should match everything after the last underscore ... or the whole string if there is no underscore.

In the following example, python 3.6 creates s == 'a_Z', whereas python 3.7 creates 'a_ZZ'

```
$ docker run --rm  python:3.6-alpine python -c "import re;s=re.sub(r'[^_]*$','Z','a_b');assert s == 'a_Z',s"

$ docker run --rm  python:3.7-alpine python -c "import re;s=re.sub(r'[^_]*$','Z','a_b');assert s == 'a_Z',s"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: a_ZZ
```

Same error with 3.8-alpine, 3.9-rc-buster.

Comment: There are several *"Changed in version 3.7"* in https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, did you review those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> *Changed in version 3.7:* Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match.

There are *two* matches of your pattern in `'a_b'`, because the pattern includes `*`: the `b`; and an empty match after it. You can see this in e.g. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cbqEKj/1), or using `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^_]*$', 'a_b')
['b', '']
```

If you switch to `+`, you'll get the expected result.

Comment: @MarkBorgerding that would make sense, anything that removes or ignores the empty match.

Comment: So it looks like re.sub is now quite error prone with patterns that can match the empty string.

Comment: adding `count=1` to re.sub limits the substitution, but is there any way to know that the one subst will be the longest (i.e. not the empty string)

Comment: If you don't want to replace empty matches, write patterns that don't give empty matches (as I suggest in the answer, `r'[^_]+$'` would work). I wouldn't describe it as error prone, that change was a bugfix.

Comment: The rationale is at https://bugs.python.org/issue32308

Comment: Interestingly, this change also broke an example in python docs.  look for "abxd" in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Comment: I tend to side with the naysayers at https://bugs.python.org/issue32308  : Anders Hovmöller ("those others are broken") and David Barnett ("baffled by the new behavior").

Comment: @MarkBorgerding please take that up on the bug tracker if you want; SO isn't a place to relitigate language changes, and I don't want to get into a discussion about whether that was a "correct" change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211801/discussion-between-mark-borgerding-and-jonrsharpe).